# Using header('Refresh...') to refresh the page

Tags: php

I'm not sure what is wrong with this? (I know the URL is currently in this example), but why would this not work? It works fine on localhost, so why not on my http server?

```
<?php
header('Refresh:10; url=https://finesseshop.ca/**secret page**');
?>
```

Comment: do you get any errors, what is not working? do you need to show the page for 10 seconds or just need to redirect right away?

Comment: need to show page. no errors

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` right after the opening `<?php` tag and try again.

Comment: it says header already sent, but i have no other headers?

Comment: show all your code. you probably `echo` or `print` something before the `header`

Comment: it says that it cant start sessions either, why does godaddy do that?

Comment: Your `header()` contents are invalid - the string will only work for a `<meta>` tag. Use `Location: [url]` instead if you want to use HTTP headers. I have no idea why this works fine in your dev environment - it should not, as far as I know.

Comment: there is no Refresh header !!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid - HTTP headers cannot be used to cause a delayed redirect, and there's no `Refresh` header at all.

A `Location` header will redirect immediately. If you need the delay, you can use [a meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or a JavaScript `setTimeout`.

> it says header already sent

That's a separate issue, but the code you show - *by itself* - cannot cause that error. Consult [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) for information on what causes that error.